# Basic Java Programming

Tags: java

i just want to ask for your help about this code, i'm having a hard time getting the payment value if the payment option selected by the user is via installment.!
your feedback.answer will be appreciated.

```
public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String name = "";
            float Subtotal=0, totalLec = 0, totalLab = 0, payment=0, Apayment;
            int lecPay = 250, labPay = 750;
            short lec_unit, lab_unit, choice;

            System.out.println("Enter Student Name:");
            name = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Number of Lecture Units: ");

            lec_unit = input.nextShort();
               \\`enter code here`
            System.out.println("Enter Number of Lab Units: ");

            lab_unit = input.nextShort();
            System.out.println("Payment Type");
            System.out.println("[1] Full Payment (CASH)");
            System.out.println("[2] Installment");
            System.out.println("Choice: ");
            choice = input.nextShort();

            if (choice == 1) {
                totalLec = lec_unit * lecPay;
                System.out.println("Total Number of Lecture Units: " + lec_unit);
                System.out.println("Total Number of Lab Units: " + lab_unit);
                System.out.println("Total Tuition Fee: " + totalLec);
                totalLab = lab_unit * labPay;
                System.out.println("Total Laboratory Fee: " + totalLab);
                Subtotal = totalLab + totalLec;
                System.out.println("Subtotal: " + Subtotal);
            } 
            else if (choice == 2) {
                System.out.println("Choose Number of Payment[2/3/4]");
                choice = input.nextShort();
                if (choice == 2) {
                    Apayment = (short) Subtotal * (short) .10;
                    payment = Apayment + Subtotal;
                    System.out.println("Amount Payable: " + payment);
                } 
                else if (choice == 3) {
                    Apayment = (short) Subtotal * 15;
                    payment = Apayment + Subtotal;
                    System.out.println("Amount Payable: " + payment);
                } 
                else if (choice == 4) {
                    Apayment = (short) Subtotal * 20;
                    payment = Apayment + Subtotal;
                    System.out.println("Amount Payable: " + payment);
                } 
                else {
                    System.out.println("Option Invalid");        
                }

            } 
            else {
                System.out.println("Option Invalid");
            }
```

Comment: So what happens when you run this? What do you want to happen that isn't happening?

Comment: It is not showing the correct amount payable if the option selected is via installment..

Comment: I think this part is not correct though i have tried to revise it but still wont show the amount payable..  Subtotal=totalLab+totalLec;
Apayment = (short) Subtotal * (short) .10;
payment = Apayment + Subtotal;
System.out.println("Amount Payable: " + payment);

Comment: Does it output anything?

Comment: Yes Eamon, it shows a 0 value for the payment.

Comment: @user3779894 Set a breakpoint at the start of your program and step through it, you will easily see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Subtotal is set to 0 at the begining.

If you select option 2, Subtotal is still 0 so

```
Subtotal*0.10 =0
```

And if you write

```
Apayment = (short) Subtotal * (short) .10;
payment = Apayment + Subtotal;
```

it means

```
payment = Subtotal * 0.10  +  Subtotal * 0.10
```

So it will still be 0.

Comment: but i have declared that Subtotal = totalLab + totalLec; so it means that the value of Subtotal is the sum of totalLab and total lec?? do i need to indicate the value again in the else statement?

Comment: Yes but you do this operation only when choice==1.  So if you choose "2", you won't go in this block and your Subtotal will be 0.

Comment: Thank you! Jhamon! no i get it, i have declared the value of Subtotal if the option selected was 1. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You initialise Subtotal to 0. Then you only update it's value if choice == 1 but only print the result if choice == 2.

Try changing your code to this:

```
            if (choice == 1) {
                totalLec = lec_unit * lecPay;
                System.out.println("Total Number of Lecture Units: " + lec_unit);
                System.out.println("Total Number of Lab Units: " + lab_unit);
                System.out.println("Total Tuition Fee: " + totalLec);
                totalLab = lab_unit * labPay;
                System.out.println("Total Laboratory Fee: " + totalLab);
                Subtotal = totalLab + totalLec;
                System.out.println("Subtotal: " + Subtotal);
            //  "else if(choice==2)" { <-- remove this
                System.out.println("Choose Number of Payment[2/3/4]");
                choice = input.nextShort();
            ...
            // }                       <-- and the accompanying closing brace
```